# .htaccess not working properly while setting SSL redirects only on certain pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

While looking for an answer for the question above I have encountered this script as a solution(I would like to have my website on http except of a few pages like login, register,manage etc.):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force https for /login.php and /register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(login|register)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This exact example should work on my server, but it works only partially, meaning, it redirects all pages to http, but I am unable to open login.php or register.php. The webbrowser states that these pages include redirect loop and they can't show up. By no means I am not an expert on mode_rewrite or htaccess so I would appreciate any help.

edit:
I have followed the suggestions and run mywebsite with chrome plugin. I discovered that in the page login.php has redirect loop http->https->http etc. (The only other redirection on that page is when the user is already signed, but it doesn't seem ike a couse for this loop). I have tried also different codes for setting SSL and this one works:

```
# Rewrite Rules for example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL on for payments
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but payments
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And this one is working correctly, but it has only one exception for https and I would like to have more of them(around 6). Has someone any idea why the first script is not working? or how to modify the second one in order to have more https websites?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some CMS/php framework running?

Comment: This works correctly for me. I suppose there is something else that is redirecting the user. This can be an other rule in .htaccess, a rule in httpd.conf or even a Location-header in your file. I use [this chrome-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll) to figure out what redirect loop is going on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have checked the redirections with this chrome plugin and it turned out the the server is redirecting the browser endlessly to login.php via http->https->http... etc. On my website I am using php class uFlex for handling login and registration, but I have checked the source code and I have only one redirection - if user is signed(so it shouldn't redirect in this case). I don't have any other code in my .htaccess. Do you have any other ideas what it would be?

Comment: I was doing some tests and noticed that if I replace ^/(login|register)\.php$ with \/login\.php [NC] it works, so I start to think that it is a syntax problem. As far as I know because of this change I can do only 1 execption to https. Is there a way to modify this script so that I will be able to put more exceptions to https?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, this is what worked for me.

In your httpd.conf, under virtual hosts, make sure you have both:

ServerName domain.com

ServerAlias www.domain.com

BOTH in VirtualHost *:80 AND VirtualHost *:443